# TWRP build ninja error: 'import_includes' and 'export_includes' missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: android

Error building TWRP image for my device:

```
gatnewhou@DESKTOP-MRIRG97:/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp$ lunch omni_Teracube_One-eng 
WARNING: device/teracube/Teracube_One/omni.dependencies file not found
```

Lunching only provides that error.

```
gatnewhou@DESKTOP-MRIRG97:/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp$ mka recoveryimage
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=16.1.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=omni_Teracube_One
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-19041-Microsoft-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.4-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ3B.190801.002
OUT_DIR=/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out
============================================
12:34:59 Missing ninja log: stat /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/.ninja_log: no such file or directory
[1/1] /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
[38/39] glob prebuilts/ndk/stl.bp
[76/76] /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/soong/build.ninja
/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/build-omni_Teracube_One-cleanspec.ninja is missing, regenerating...
/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/build-omni_Teracube_One.ninja is missing, regenerating...
[81/147] including frameworks/base/Android.mk ...
find: ‘../opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony’: No such file or directory    
find: ‘../opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony/gsm’: No such file or directory
find: ‘../opt/net/voip/src/java/android/net/rtp’: No such file or directory       
find: ‘../opt/net/voip/src/java/android/net/sip’: No such file or directory       
find: ‘../opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony’: No such file or directory
find: ‘../opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony/gsm’: No such file or directory
find: ‘../opt/net/voip/src/java/android/net/rtp’: No such file or directory       
find: ‘../opt/net/voip/src/java/android/net/sip’: No such file or directory       
[127/147] including system/core/Android.mk ...
sed: can't read development/sdk/plat_tools_source.prop_template: No such file or directory
sed: can't read development/sdk/plat_tools_source.prop_template: No such file or directory
[138/147] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...
system/sepolicy/Android.mk:79: warning: BOARD_SEPOLICY_VERS not specified, assuming current platform version
[147/147] including vendor/omni/Android.mk ...
vendor/omni/build/tasks/kernel.mk:167: warning: ***************************************************************
vendor/omni/build/tasks/kernel.mk:168: warning: * Using prebuilt kernel binary instead of source              *
vendor/omni/build/tasks/kernel.mk:169: warning: * THIS IS DEPRECATED, AND WILL BE DISCONTINUED                *
vendor/omni/build/tasks/kernel.mk:170: warning: * Please configure your device to download the kernel         *
vendor/omni/build/tasks/kernel.mk:171: warning: * source repository to kernel/teracube/Teracube_One
vendor/omni/build/tasks/kernel.mk:172: warning: * for more information                                        *
vendor/omni/build/tasks/kernel.mk:173: warning: ***************************************************************
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: overriding commands for target `/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: overriding commands for target `/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/root/res/images/charger/battery_scale.png'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/root/res/images/charger/battery_scale.png'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/system/etc/mkshrc'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/system/etc/mkshrc'
[ 99% 689/690] glob hardware/interfaces/camera/metadata/3.2/src
ninja: error: '/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/bootctrl._intermediates/export_includes', needed by '/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/obj/EXECUTABLES/update_engine_sideload_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
12:37:52 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (02:59 (mm:ss)) ####
```

This is my first time building a TWRP image. I generated the device tree with this [tool](https://github.com/SebaUbuntu/TWRP-device-tree-generator). Do I need to provide these files or make empty files for "export_includes" and "import_includes" so that it can generate?

Same error occurs when trying to use [`export USE_NINJA=false`](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=71946118&postcount=5)

Perhaps I am missing [proprietary blobs](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/5r5nuf/lineageos_build_error_with_latest_source/dd4u6ib/?context=10000)?

**EDIT:** Made some progress but still running into some errors

```sh
FAILED: /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/ramdisk-recovery.cpio
/bin/bash -c "(mkdir -p /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery ) && (mkdir -p /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/etc /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/sdcard /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/tmp ) && (rsync -a --exclude=etc --exclude=sdcard --exclude=vendor --exclude=/root/sepolicy --exclude=/root/plat_file_contexts --exclude=/root/vendor_file_contexts --exclude=/root/plat_property_contexts --exclude=/root/vendor_property_contexts --exclude=cache /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/root /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery ) && (cp -f /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/system/bin/adbd /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/sbin/adbd ) && (find /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root -maxdepth 1 -name 'init*.rc' -type f -not -name \"init.recovery.*.rc\" | xargs rm -f ) && (cp -f bootable/recovery/etc/init.rc /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/ ) && (cp /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/root/init.recovery.*.rc /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/ || true ) && (mkdir -p /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/res ) && (rm -rf /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/res/* ) && (cp -rf bootable/recovery/res-xhdpi/* /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/res ) && (cp -f bootable/recovery/fonts/12x22.png /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/res/images/font.png ) && (cp -rf device/teracube/Teracube_One/recovery/root /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/ ) && (cp -f device/teracube/Teracube_One/recovery.fstab /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/etc/recovery.fstab ) && (cp /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/obj/PACKAGING/ota_keys_intermediates/keys /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/res/keys ) && (cat /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/root/default.prop > /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/prop.default ) && (cat /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/obj/ETC/system_build_prop_intermediates/build.prop >> /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/prop.default ) && (ln -sf prop.default /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root/default.prop ) && (/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/mkbootfs /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root > /mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/ramdisk-recovery.cpio )"
rsync: chgrp "/mnt/m/Documents/GitHub/twrp/out/target/product/Teracube_One/recovery/root" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
17:11:30 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (07:43 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Looks like an error with NTFS partitions. Aliasing rsync to `rsync --progress --modify-window=1 --update --recursive --times`

Detailed documentation found on [my repo issue](https://github.com/gatlinnewhouse/Teracube_twrp-device-tree/issues/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was resolved by making TWRP on linux instead of on WSL 2.

Full details on my github error thread: https://github.com/gatlinnewhouse/Teracube_twrp-device-tree/issues/1